# How to get the angle of an UIElement in Windows Phone Silverlight?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am stuck with this code and I cant find how to get the angle of this Path element in code behind , please help me ! My purpose is checking the angle of 'vectorCapture' when its parent element 'CamGrid' is rotating. Thanks a lots!
 Here is my XAML code:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="RotateCamera" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation 
            Duration="0:0:10" To="360"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
            Storyboard.TargetName="CamGrid"
            d:IsOptimized="True" />
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid Name="CamGrid"
          RenderTransformOrigin=".5, .5">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="CamGridCompositeTransform" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Path Data="M4,16h1.6V5.6H16V4H4V16z M5.6,27.2H4v12h12v-1.6H5.6V27.2z M37.6,16h1.6V4h-12v1.6h10.4V16z M9.6,20.8H0v1.6
    h9.6V20.8z M20.8,43.2h1.6v-9.6h-1.6V43.2z M37.6,37.6H27.2v1.6h12v-12h-1.6V37.6z M20.8,9.6h1.6V0h-1.6V9.6z M33.6,20.8v1.6h9.6
    v-1.6H33.6z M33.6,20.8"
              Name="vectorCapture"
              Fill="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ForeColor2,
            Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
              Stroke="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ForeColor2,
            Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
              StrokeThickness="2"
              Height="64"
              Width="64"
              Margin="0,0,0,0"
              Stretch="Uniform"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, here is my solution:

```
CompositeTransform CamCT = new CompositeTransform();
CamCT = (CompositeTransform)CamGrid.RenderTransform;
//then get angle by CamCT.Rotation
```

Comment: ok, thanks actually i want the same code because i'm making color picker from the image so i need